# Output numbers from a string containing hex and decimal values

Tags: c#, int, hex, type-conversion, decimal

I am scraping data off of a website to get helpful data for my coworkers, instead of having to refresh the page frequently.

The C# code pulls data straight from the HTML. But the data is encrypted in a strange way, and returns as a non human-readable string, which is not helpful to us.

For example, in the table, a product number may be shown as "14501219". In the HTML, the inner text of the element containing the data is "&#49;4501&#x32;&#x31;&#x39;".

I need to know how to:

1. Parse hex and decimal into int from the same string
2. Append those results to the eventual output

So far I worked this out this pseudocode, but I don't know how it would look in C# or what conversion methods to use:

```
for (int i = 0; i < inputString.Length; i++)
   {
      if (inputString[i] = '&' && inputstring[i+1] = '#')
           {
                if (inputstring[i+2 = 'x'
                {
                     //convert to hex
                     //append to outputList
                }
                else
                {
                    //convert to decimal
                    //append to outputList
                }
            }
      else
            {
                 //convert to string literal
            }
   }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Do you know if the string you are seeing is a string literal of a hex or a series of raw byte numbers?

Comment: I fixed it, Markdown automatically converted the original string to the desired number when I typed it in.

Comment: @lrb I am not sure. How would I know if it's a string literal or raw bytes?

Comment: I think that is the ascii representation of the character or number, for example, ctrl lf has an ascii equivalent.10/13 or something, cant remember. You just need to escape the characters, perhaps encode/decode the url. Url.Decode()?

Comment: This can be solved with an "HTML-entity decode". That walk though the string and turn each HTML entity (eg. "&#49;") into the respective number (eg. 1). If doing it by hand, the easiest way is to use a `Regex.Replace` with a replacement function, and matching on `@"&#(\d\d);"`. Then the replacement function will get the value, such as "49" and be allowed to return the relevant converted "1" value - see an ASCII character table.

Comment: How would I do that in C#?

Comment: @user2864740 Thanks, I'll try that when I get in tomorrow and update the question.

Comment: No trick to this, just use System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode.

Comment: @Brickhau5 A byte is just 8-bits, it is not hex, octal, decimal, ASCII or anything. Hex, decimal, ASCII, UTF-8, UTF16, etc are just different ways to display bytes and not all bytes can be displayed in all these formats. In particular not all bytes are ASCII and some of those are are not displayable. Unicode is even pickier about what byte sequences are and are not valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you added the string literal example I new what you were seeing/asking. In order for the http client side not to get tripped up on some special charecters thaey are endoded using the acsii representation. Most frameworks have a way of working with the encoded url. For example in c# you should always make sure to use [HttpUtility.UrlDecode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urldecode(v=vs.110).aspx) and [HttpUtility.UrlEncode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urlencode(v=vs.110).aspx) internally when reading and writing.